# Can I write a loop within the colnames function

Tags: loops, dplyr, multiple-columns, rename

I have several variables that I want to rename. Since the variables are always part of the questionnaire, the renaming is done according to a system.

Until now, I have renamed each variable manually, but I wonder if it is possible to create a loop that always systematically uses the correct variable name.

Data:

```r
structure(list(PCL.01.01.t1 = 1, PCL.01.02.t1 = 1, PCL.01.03.t1 = 1, 
    PCL.01.04.t1 = 1, PCL.01.05.t1 = 1, PCL.01.06.t1 = 1, PCL.01.07.t1 = 1, 
    PCL.01.08.t1 = 1, PCL.01.09.t1 = 1, PCL.01.10.t1 = 1, PCL.01.11.t1 = 1, 
    PCL.01.12.t1 = 1, PCL.01.13.t1 = 1, PCL.01.14.t1 = 1, PCL.01.15.t1 = 1, 
    PCL.01.16.t1 = 1, PCL.01.17.t1 = 1), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1L)) -> data_MUENSTER
```

My code so far (that works) but I want to do it faster and more elegantly.

```r
colnames (data_MUENSTER) [colnames(data_MUENSTER) %in% c("PCL.01.01.t1", "PCL.01.02.t1", "PCL.01.03.t1", "PCL.01.04.t1", "PCL.01.05.t1", "PCL.01.06.t1",
"PCL.01.07.t1", "PCL.01.08.t1", "PCL.01.09.t1", "PCL.01.10.t1", "PCL.01.11.t1", "PCL.01.12.t1", "PCL.01.13.t1","PCL.01.14.t1", "PCL.01.15.t1","PCL.01.16.t1", "PCL.01.17.t1")] <- c("PCL.01.01", "PCL.01.02", "PCL.01.03", "PCL.01.04", "PCL.01.05", "PCL.01.06", "PCL.01.07", "PCL.01.08","PCL.01.09", "PCL.01.10", "PCL.01.11", "PCL.01.12", "PCL.01.13", "PCL.01.14",
"PCL.01.15", "PCL.01.16", "PCL.01.17")
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you're doing is removing the `.t1` from all columns, you can simply use `rename_with()` from `dplyr` and combine it with a simple `gsub()` call:

```r
rename_with(data_MUENSTER, ~ gsub(".t1", "", .x, fixed = TRUE))
```

Comment: That makes sense to me. When trying to run the code, I get an error though

Comment: Error: 'num_ansi_colors' ist kein von 'namespace:cli' exportiertes Objekt

Comment: I can't reproduce the error - the code works well on my side. Try updating package `cli` (I'm not sure how this code is calling `cli`...)